# How do I find if included JavaScript files are actually needed on different pages?

Tags: javascript, include, audit, web-crawler

I am looking for a way to spider a site (or a list of top pages) and determine whether a JS file included on the relevant page is actually needed, or alternatively what pages DO require particular JS files.

Server-side language is PHP. The actual spidering of pages wont be a problem.

I've inherited a very* large site. Up until now the convention was that if a JavaScript file was needed on any sub-page, it would generally be put in the  template for every page. No conditions. No minification. No concatenation.

Going forward we will be rolling out require.js but for now something needs to be done on the legacy pages.

- 30k+ files in web directory, Google indexes 350k+ pages for the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Whether a js file is needed depends on what data or effect you want in some web page. There seems no common way to to do this for all sites.

If you just want to get some data on a web page which is generated by loading a js file, like the price and stock on a commodity page, then you have to use [requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) to retrieve the html page and parse the page to see whether the data you want is on the static page. If not, the data may be generated by a js file and you should use *google developer tools* in chrome or *firebug* to determine which js file is needed.

Beyond that, I don't know whether there's another scene needing to determine whether a js file is needed when you want to crawl a site.

If you don't want to do the analysis work like the above, just use some **headless-browser** technique to crawl a site, like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)(which is recommended), qtwebkit or selenium.